# How to extract string value based on delimiters

Tags: excel, delimiter

I need help with an Excel formula to extract a value from a string, based on delimiters.

This is the string I would like to extract the first 10 fields from: `ES_ABC_FACEBOOK_SocialImage_FACEBOOK_Reach(CPM)_DEM_18-45_Apr19_abc_def_ghi`

In other words, I would need to get `ES_ABC_FACEBOOK_SocialImage_FACEBOOK_Reach(CPM)_DEM_18-45_Apr19_abc`

Bearing in mind that the number of fields (separated by delimiters) may vary in the dataset but that I need to consistently only pick up the first 10 fields and drop however many fields are succeeding the 10th field.

Thanks in advance!

Robin

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
=LEFT(<your cell>,FIND("||",SUBSTITUTE(<your cell>,"_","||",10))-1)
```

e.g. `=LEFT(A1,FIND("||",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","||",10))-1)`

The formula finds the 10th underscore, and the gives you all the characters up to it (minus the underscore).

If you need to change how many fields it gives you back, change the 10. The -1 at the end just removes the final underscore. Of note, the || is just a simple set of characters I can't imagine will ever appear in your strings. If it does, something else will need to be selected.

Lastly, if some of your strings will have less than 10 fields, try:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("||",SUBSTITUTE(<your cell>,"_","||",10))-1),<your cell>,LEFT(<your cell>,FIND("||",SUBSTITUTE(<your cell>,"_","||",10))-1))
```

This gives you the whole string in the event that there are less than 10 fields.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, you nailed it!

Comment: Lovely - glad it worked for you. If the answer is correct, do please mark it as correct to help any future viewers.